# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition never called

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to use the getLocation of the browser but everytime it goes to the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition, nothing happens, i tried the put the website in https, change the codes, nothing happens still, the success function never get fired.

```
function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                alert('it works');
            }, function (error) {
                alert('Error occurred. Error code: ' + error.code);
            }, { timeout: 5000 });
        } else {
            alert('no geolocation support');
        }
    };
```

Any idea where the error coming from ? i tested it on chrome

Comment: Does the browser ask for permissions to access your geolocation?